# Please enter a value between NaN and NaN range validation

Tags: html, jquery, validation, magento, magento2

I have a range slider with a code below

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
      <input name="am_giftcard_amount_slider" id="am_giftcard_amount_slider" type="range" min="0" value="13" max="27" step="1" class="gg-slider validate-range range-0-27">
</div>
```

Now I've been getting this error

```
`Please enter a value between NaN and NaN`
```

Now I tried to debug this and went to modify the file in `lib/web/mage/validation.js` now under the function `validate-range` I added a hardcode value of True just to make debug and know if the response is true if the error message still appear. But after adding the `return true` the error message is still displaying. I'm looking at this error

```
'validate-range': [
        function (v, elm) {
            
            var minValue, maxValue, ranges, reRange, result, values,
                i, name, validRange, minValidRange, maxValidRange;
            
            if ($.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(v)) {
                return true;
            } else if ($.validator.methods['validate-digits'] && $.validator.methods['validate-digits'](v)) {

                minValue = maxValue = $.mage.parseNumber(v);
            } else {
                ranges = /^(-?\d+)?-(-?\d+)?$/.exec(v);
                if (ranges) {
                    minValue = $.mage.parseNumber(ranges[1]);
                    maxValue = $.mage.parseNumber(ranges[2]);

                    if (minValue > maxValue) { //eslint-disable-line max-depth
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            reRange = /^range-(-?\d+)?-(-?\d+)?$/;
            result = true;
            values = $(elm).prop('class').split(' ');
            for (i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                name = values[i];
                validRange = reRange.exec(name);
                if (validRange) {
                    minValidRange = $.mage.parseNumber(validRange[1]);
                    maxValidRange = $.mage.parseNumber(validRange[2]);
                    result = result &&
                        (isNaN(minValidRange) || minValue >= minValidRange) &&
                        (isNaN(maxValidRange) || maxValue <= maxValidRange);

                }
            }
            return result;
        },
        $.mage.__('The value is not within the specified range.')
    ],
```

Not sure why even though I added the return true the error validation is still displaying. Can anyone tell me where I can debug and how to turn this off? I'm basically clueless now on where to look for because I already modified the js but it is still throwing this error. Any idea on how to debug this please and is there any error in my code?

Note: I didn't modify or add any JQuery Slider initialization I just added the HTML markup for slider

Update:

I tried this code

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
      <input name="am_giftcard_amount_slider" id="am_giftcard_amount_slider" type="range" min="0" digits="true" value="13" max="27" range="2,17" step="1" class="gg-slider ignore">
</div>
```

After I place the `range="2,17"` I got this error

```
`Please enter a value between 2 and NaN`
```

I know I put 2 instead of 0 for the minimum. I intentionally made it so that I will know if it's actually retrieving the correct parameter. Now based on this. It was able to get `2` as the minimum but why is the max `17` not being read?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the message `Please enter a value between NaN and NaN` is from jquery validation system not magento one because magento only return this message : "*The value is not within the specified range.*".

You should considere using the `validate-digits-range` and `digits-range-2-17` classes which is a magento validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else getting `Please enter a value between NaN and NaN range validation` error from Jquery Validation, you need to setup validate function for range input validation rule properly before validating.

In my case:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        rangeInputId: {
            range: [3, 10]
        }
    },
});
```